# Can't start Xdebug session in PHPStorm

Tags: php, xdebug

I have encounter one problem when I am using PHPStorm 8 under Mac OS, I make some PHP files and I want to debug, but seems my XDebug does not work at all. All my break points just are ignored. I checked my configuration twice and I have tried the online tools on  http://xdebug.org/wizard.php
   Here's my configuration of my php.ini.

```
[XDebug]
;zend_extension=opcache.so
zend_extension = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
```

and I also validated on the phpstorm like that.
[image]

I don't know why is that? Anybody has any idea?

Jason

Comment: How did you start the xDebug Session?

Comment: just press the button of debug.